# When is full list slice used?

Tags: python, list, slice

So I understand that if I have a list like

```
>>> dinner = ['steak', 'baked potato', 'red wine']
```

then the slice with unspecified beginning and endpoints is the whole list

```
>>> dinner[:]
['steak', 'baked potato', 'red wine']
```

My question is if this full list slice is ever used in practice, and, if so, what is the use case for it? Why not just reference the list `dinner` without the slice notation `[:]`?

Comment: To make a copy, for instance if you want to *iterate* and *modify* the same list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A full list slice is the usual Python syntax to make a shallow copy of a list.

```
>>> dinner = ['steak', 'baked potato', 'red wine']
>>> dinner1 = dinner  # just another reference to the original object
>>> dinner2 = dinner[:]  # makes a new object
>>> dinner[0] = 'spam'
>>> dinner1  # dinner1 reflects the change to dinner
['spam', 'baked potato', 'red wine']
>>> dinner2  # dinner2 doesn't reflect the change to dinner
['steak', 'baked potato', 'red wine']
```

If you just reference the original list without a slice, you will also see changes to the original list in your new reference.  That's sometimes what you want, and sometimes not what you want.

Comment: You can also assign to the slice to modify the original list, even blank it out, e.g. `dinner[:] = []`

Comment: So in python the variable is a pointer to the list rather than the list itself. That makes sense to have this notation now.

Comment: @wogsland I strongly suggest to watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns

Answer (score 3):

If used on the LHS of the assignment operator, a full list slice is used to mutate a list *in-place*:

```
>>> dinner = ['steak', 'baked potato', 'red wine']
>>> dinner[:] = ['pasta']
>>> dinner
['pasta']
```

Otherwise, a full list slice usually comes handy when you need to modify/mutate the original list, say in a loop, and you need to keep a reference copy, more approriately called a shallow copy:

```
for i in dinner[:]:
    # mutate dinner without running into problems
```

This allows the behavior of the for loop to be consistent with the state of the original list.

You could also create a shallow copy by using [`copy.copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) or calling `list` on the original list, but `[:]` is more generally used, being a language construct and also less verbose.

Comment: Passing a copy in the loop seems very handy.